# Printing straight from the browser

Tags: desktop-printer, octoprint

Are there any browser extensions or printers with OctoPrint built in that would allow me to print straight from the browser?

Thinking of a workflow like this:

1. Make something with Tinkercad (or other online service)
2. download stl or obj
3. select print from bookmark or dropdown menu
4. print is sent to printer and starts printing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was the [CuraEngine](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/curalegacy/) plugin, but it's not really maintained anymore. It should still work though

Answer (score 1):

This works for OctoPI (OctoPrint on a Raspberry Pi).

1. Add the Samba package to your OctoPrint machine.
2. open an SMB connection to that machine from your browser machine
3. Save your STL to `/home/pi/.octoprint/uploads` on the Raspberry Pi.

You can save directly from your slicer the same way.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for. My usecase is a chromebook so I need some way to slice the model in the browser.